# How to get the number of rows affected by the insert using table adapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How to get the number of rows affected by the insert using table adapter.?

I have this example class,

```
public void InsertLeave(DateTime sd, DateTime ed,string reason, string type, int empid)
{
    Adapter.InsertLeave(sd, ed, reason, type, empid);
}
```

its return void, but I would like to return an int of affected row by this insert.

Comment: `InsertLeave` and it's overloaded version  are functions of yourself, so you should at least show your overloaded `InsertLeave`. Then we can tell you how you get the affected records back. Normally you would use `TableAdapter.Update` which returns the number of affected records.

Comment: INSERT INTO tblLeave
(startdate, enddate, reason, leavetype, EmpId)
VALUES (@sd,@ed,@reason,@type,@emp)

Is this what you want see??

Comment: No, i wanted to see where you call `TableAdapter.Update`

Answer (score 0):

Could you copy and paste the method signature and body for the Adapter.InsertLeave method?

If the ExecuteMode for the Adapter.InsertLeave is set to Scalar/Non Query when you created it through the wizard, it will return an int value; one returns how many rows are affected and the other one returns the id of the row inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to change/edit method `InsertLeave` then add another output parameter and get that accordingly.

```
public void InsertLeave(DateTime sd, DateTime ed,string reason, string type, int empid)
{
    int rowsEffected = 0;
    Adapter.InsertLeave(sd, ed, reason, type, empid, out rowsEffected);
    //Now you've available number of rows effected into `rowsEffected`
}
```

OR

Change return type void to int of the method `InsertLeave`

Thanks